# Hibernate Group by query - column not exist?

Tags: hibernate

Please help me to solve this hibernate query:

I have class Customer, items, and category; and I am trying to find the sum of 
items from a customer, group by category

```
hql.append("Select sum(amount), category From Item ")
        .append(" Where owner=:owner")
        .append(" And month(createOn)=:month")
        .append(" And year(createOn)=:year");

    hql.append(" group by category");

    Query query = getQuery(hql.toString())
                        .setParameter("owner", owner)
                        .setParameter("month", month)
                        .setParameter("year", year)
                        ;


    List<Object[]> resultList = query.list();
    List<ItemHolder> itemHolderList = new ArrayList<ItemHolder>();

    for(Object[] obj : resultList) {
        ItemHolder bo = ItemHolder.getInstance();
        bo.setAmount((BigDecimal) obj[0]);
        bo.setCategory((Category)obj[1]);
        itemHolderList.add(bo);

    }

    return itemHolderList;
```

This is my item class:

```
@Column(name="AMOUNT")
private BigDecimal amount;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
private Customer owner;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="CAT_ID")
private Category category;


@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATEON")
private Date createOn;
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column "owner" does not exist
```

Comment: Was `owner` added following the last schema generation?  i.e. is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to something other than update?

Comment: I set it to update. However, I dont think it the cause because if I taken the "category" out, the query will run normally.

Comment: Your error message indicates `column "owner" does not exist`.  Something doesn't add up.